# Applying and Visualizing k means clustering on a data set that has 9 features

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I had a data set of images that I have extracted 9 numerical features that I want to apply k means clustering or hierarchical clustering to. I'm just not sure how to go about it. The tutorials I have read all only have 2 or 3 features to them, so it's easy to apply and graph. Any help would be appreciated

Here's the code I have so far:

```
numpyArr = df.values


ms = MeanShift()
ms.fit(numpyArr)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_
n_clusters_ = len(np.unique(labels))
print("Number of estimated clusters:", n_clusters_)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a dimensionality reduction algorithm like PCA method after performing clustering, to reduce the dimension of your clustered data into two dimensions and then visualize the clusters.

Comment: So I would apply normal clustering using my data set then use PCA to visualize it? How would I go about doing that

Comment: Yes exactly. Please check the following link https://medium.com/@dmitriy.kavyazin/principal-component-analysis-and-k-means-clustering-to-visualize-a-high-dimensional-dataset-577b2a7a5fe2

Comment: oh wow great article. I'll def try this out. Thank you!

Comment: @somedude1234 you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Same as visualizing 9 dimensional data:

- scatter plot *matrix* with 9x9 scatterplots
- dimensionality reduction
- parallel coordinates
- whisker plots
- ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to visualise the data after K-Means, the better approach would be to reduce the dimensionality to two or three dimensions and visualise using a matplotlib 2D or 3D plot.
You might also try pair plots but I don't think It would be much helpful from clustering stand point.